Node.js fs.existsSync returning false postives
I have the following code:
  const fs = await import("fs");
    let hashedPassword;

    if (!fs.existsSync(".fs")) {
      fs.mkdirSync(".fs");
      console.info("No cache found. Creating .fs");
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(".fs/token.txt")) {
      console.info("No token found, hashing a new one");
      hashedPassword = bcypt.hashSync(
        password || (process.env.UNIVERSAL_FS_PASSWORD as string),
        10
      );

      fs.writeFileSync(".fs/token.txt", hashedPassword);
    }

    // TODO: add correct url
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${hashedPassword}`
      }
    });

    if (response.status === 401) {
      console.error("Failed to authenticate. Check your password");
    } else if (response.status === 200) {
      console.info("Authenticated");
    } else if (response.status === 500) {
      console.info("Something else went wrong. Check your server logs");
    }

It checks if the .fs folder exists. If it does than the token is used for auth. If not it hashes a new one. The fs folder does not exists but when consoling the same fs.existsSync I get the result true. However it does not exists.
Running the ls command where the exists call is checking shows that no .fs folder exists:
README.md         eslint.config.js  package.json      rollup.config.mjs tests             types
dist              node_modules      pnpm-lock.yaml    src               tsconfig.json     vite.config.ts

To get more info I consoled fs.stat and this was the result:
Stats {
  dev: 16777232,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 52057046,
  size: 60,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1719445593768.046,
  mtimeMs: 1719445593768.1392,
  ctimeMs: 1719445593768.1392,
  birthtimeMs: 1719445593768.046
}

It seems Node still thinks the dir and file exist on my system. Envinfo:
  System:
    OS: macOS 14.5
    CPU: (12) arm64 Apple M2 Max
    Memory: 8.82 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 22.3.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    npm: 10.8.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    pnpm: 9.4.0 - ~/Library/pnpm/pnpm
    bun: 1.1.17 - ~/.bun/bin/bun
  Managers:
    Homebrew: 4.3.7 - /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
    pip3: 24.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
    RubyGems: 3.0.3.1 - /usr/bin/gem
  Utilities:
    Make: 3.81 - /usr/bin/make
    GCC: 15.0.0 - /usr/bin/gcc
    Git: 2.39.3 - /usr/bin/git
    Clang: 15.0.0 - /usr/bin/clang
    FFmpeg: 7.0.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg
    Curl: 8.6.0 - /usr/bin/curl
    OpenSSL: 3.3.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl
  Servers:
    Apache: 2.4.58 - /usr/sbin/apachectl
  Virtualization:
    Docker: 26.1.4 - /usr/local/bin/docker
    Docker Compose: 2.27.1 - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    Parallels: 19.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/prlctl
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.5, iOS 17.5, macOS 14.5, tvOS 17.5, visionOS 1.2, watchOS 10.5
  IDEs:
    VSCode: 1.90.2 - /usr/local/bin/code
    Vim: 9.0 - /usr/bin/vim
    Xcode: 15.4/15F31d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Bash: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Java: 21.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
    Perl: 5.34.1 - /usr/bin/perl
    Python3: 3.12.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
    Ruby: 2.6.10 - /usr/bin/ruby
  Databases:
    SQLite: 3.43.2 - /usr/bin/sqlite3
  Browsers:
    Safari: 17.5


"Running the ls command where the exists call is checking shows that no .fs folder exists" Have you tried ls -la? In a lot of configurations ls doesn't show hidden files by default.

@RobbyCornelissen Running that command still does not show .fs. Checking in finder with the show hidden files option gives the same result

@Ethan it might be inside in the src folder because you didn't specified any relative url of the .fs folder, try to log this process.cwd() after the statement

Logging it out gives me the root of my project /Users/ekrich/git/universal-fs. Note that the code is being bundled with Rollup and run in the dist directory. Here is my run command npx rollup -cw & nodemon dist/index.js
